# How to get all sign-in attributes while authenticating using SAML through firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, saml, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

- React app is using firebase for SSO authentication with SAML

Example code -

```
export async function signInWithRedirectToProvider(providerId) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const provider = new SAMLAuthProvider(providerId);
  await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
}
```

In the next step - [just as mentioned in the documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/saml#web-namespaced-api_2)

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
  .then((result) => {
    // User is signed in.

    // Provider data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile,
    // or from the user's ID token obtained from result.user.getIdToken()
    // as an object in the firebase.sign_in_attributes custom claim.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error.
  });
```

Final Step -
We retrieve the user attributes associated with the SAML provider from the ID token using the `firebase.sign_in_attributes` claim.

However, the `firebase.sign_in_attributes` claim doesn't contain all the attributes those are received from the SAML assertions.

For example, the application I am working on needs to get university users data and it contains user role.

`Name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:eduPersonAffiliation"`
It seems the SAML assertion contains the attribute but `firebase.sign_in_attributes` claim excludes this attribute somehow while other attributes are present.

So, basically I am stuck here, any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

I tried tracing the logs from SAML calls and I can see the attributes there and however after firebase authentication some of the attributes are not there as the end response I receive in my application.